# While loop not rerunning while True

Tags: python, while-loop

When I check the variable 'invalid' it shows that it's True. But the while loop isn't rerunning the code. The code is checking for matches between two lists. If the 'users_word' has letters that aren't in the 'random_word' the while loop should re-run and force the user to enter a new word. But when I enter an word that will make 'invalid' True the loop doesn't re-run

```
def get_users_word():
    global invalid
    while invalid:
        invalid = False
        print(random_word)
        users_word_list = []
        user_word = input('Enter a word ')
        print(user_word)
        counter = 0
    # Checking user entered appropriate number of letters in their words
    # Checking the users word doesnt contain too many occurrences of a single letter
        if user_word.isalpha() and 10 > len(user_word) > 0:

            for letter in user_word:
                users_word_list.append(letter)

            while counter < 26:
                for letter in alphabet_for_counting:
                    if users_word_list.count(letter) <= random_word.count(letter):
                        counter += 1
                    elif users_word_list.count(letter) > random_word.count(letter) :
                        print(f'{letter} occur not equal')
                        invalid = True
                        counter += 1
            return user_word
        else:
            print('invalid word')
            invalid = True
```

Comment: I have to ask: are you actually calling your function by executing `get_users_word()`?

Comment: yes. I just tried to keep the code to a minimum for the post.

Comment: Does your function return a value? `return` will also break a while loop (and entire function of course).

Comment: That was it! There is a return at the end of the if statement. Thank you.

Comment: You need to make a [mre]. `get_users_word` is never called, plus `random_word` and `alphabet_for_counting` are not defined.

Answer (score 0):

BusyBear called to my attention that the while-loop was breaking/not rerunning because I had a return statement at the end.